# GCM w/ WiFi only tablets

Tags: android, push-notification, android-wifi, google-cloud-messaging

I posted this question on [android-gcm google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/HUnST1D0aE4) but I didn't get any response.

I have a use case where I need to update hundreds of tablets which are wi-fi only with my app and I want to use GCM to accomplish this goal. However, what I could not figure out from the docs is if I can register a wi-fi only device either w/ the IP (which might change based on the location) or using the development device ID or the wi-fi mac address.

Which of the three that I mentioned are reliable ways of sending notifications to update w/ a newer version of my app? If none of these are the right choices, what are my options since I can't have a phone number associated with these devices.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GCM relies on IP address. I use GCM on my apps and it works just fine with wifi tablets and phones on wifi.

Comment: :i am not able to figure out if GCM is working properly with wifi or not as i have successfully implement it using 3G gsm network data plan but it seems that it doesn't work with wifi.I am still stuck in this situation and couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Revewing the GCM i can't see the relevance of the ip/phone numer of your device.
It could be that you need GSM network for GCM to work, but i doubt that , i guess for tablets Google implemented a polling server or similar on the device.

You only need your google project id as your sender ID and you need to enable GCM in the google API console, you need to use the google GCM API jars in your app to obtain a registration number and send it to your own server, your server than contacts Google's using 
OAuth2 protocol sending them your registration id.
Once register every time you need to send a message to all users u just need to go overl all users in your server and make a request for them (using the value u'll get from OAuth authentication ) to googles servers.